# To test Nginx load-balancing in local system

Tags: nginx, webserver, load-balancing

I wanted to test if nginx is redirecting to node-2 if node-1 is down.

For that, I installed tomcat in my local windows machine and started 2 instances in `8080` and `9090` port

**Dont know how to configure nginx for this.** I tested by adding below blocks in nginx.conf . But still it is not working for me. Please help me on this

```
proxy_redirect ~.*:909[0-9]/(.*)$ /$1;
proxy_redirect ~.*:808[0-9]/(.*)$ /$1;

upstream localhost {

        server localhost:8080;
        server localhost:9090;
    }


server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;

    }
```

Comment: You might want to post this on either the ServerFault forum or the Linux forum, SO is really about programming, not configuring servers.  However, it is a good question, just in the wrong neighborhood to get the best attention.

Comment: upstream needs a unique name not localhost, then add 'proxy_pass...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the server block by below block

```
server {
       listen 8080;
       location / {
              proxy_pass http://localhost;
            }
        }
```